# ¿columa calculo sql dev?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

mi tabla es PROFESORES

Me da el siguiente error:

> Informe de error -
>   ORA-54002: sólo se pueden especificar funciones puras en una expresión de columna virtual
>   54002. 0000 -  "only pure functions can be specified in a virtual column expression"
>   *Cause:    Column expression contained a function whose evaluation is
>              non-deterministic.
>   *Action:   Rewrite column expression to reference only pure functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes utilizar `SYSDATE` en la definición de una columna calculada (columna virtual). La razón de esto es porque `SYSDATE` no es determinista, es decir, no siempre retorna el mismo valor.

Imagina que luego quieres definir un índice por esta columna, ¡un segundo después, el índice sería inválido!

Una posible solución para ello es definir una vista, dónde si puedes utilizar `SYSDATE` para realizar el cálculo de tu columna (virtual).

Un posible cálculo de la edad podría ser:

```
create view vprofesoresT
as
select   a.*
       , floor(months_between(SYSDATE, a.f_nacimiento) /12) as Edad
  from profesoresT;
/

select *
  from vprofesoresT;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero si quisiera una table no un view, quisiera agregar datos a esta tabla y trabajar con esto desde java, seria posible una solucion diferente aparte del sysdate.

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que quieres que esa columna cambie _automáticamente_ de valor a medida que va pasando el tiempo. Eso va en contra de la filosofía de las columnas calculadas, también llamadas virtuales. La idea de la columna virtual es que cambie solo cuando cambien los valores de la tabla (a través de un `update`), pero no de otra forma. Sobre esta idea, el motor realiza una serie de optimizaciones, además de permitir la creación de índices, como ya mencioné en mi respuesta.

Comment: Por otro lado, nada impide que hagas `insert` directamente en la vista. Al ser una vista que no tiene _joins_, el motor debiera resolverlo de manera automática. Si no lo hace, siempre puedes crearle _triggers_ `instead of`.

Comment: Entonces, si no quieres una columna virtual o calculada, el título de tu pregunta es incorrecto. Crea una columna regular y calcula su valor en un trigger _before insert_.

Comment: Entonces si quieres que cambie a medida que pasa el tiempo. Es decir, si hoy hacemos un `insert` y la persona tiene 27 años, al hacer una consulta dentro de dos años, ¿quieres obtener 27 o 29?. Si la respuesta es 29, vuelve a leer mi publicación. Si la respuesta en 27, edita tu pregunta, cambia el título y explica lo que realmente quieres. Un saludo.

Comment: Creala sin la columna edad. Utiliza el mismo script que ya tienes, eliminando la línea de esa columna. Luego, crea la vista como te explico en mi respuesta. Trabaja todo sobre la vista como si fuera la tabla, `select, insert, update, delete` debieran funcionar sin problemas.